# If isset в шаблонизаторе Twig

Tags: twig, шаблонизаторы, php

Здравствуйте подскажите пожалуйста, начал пользоваться шаблонизатором Twig, только вот не пойму как преобразовать такую запись

```
if (isset($_GET['hash']) && !empty($_GET['hash'])) {
$hash = $_GET['hash'];
}
```

Подскажите пожалуйста. Как работать в Twig с глобальными переменными.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Доступ к глобальной переменной можно получить так:

```
$loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem('templates');
$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader);
$twig->addGlobal('get', $_GET); // теперь get в шаблоне будет соответствовать $_GET
```

Проверяете:

```
{% if get.hash is defined and get.hash is not empty %}
    {% set hash = get.hash %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: @andreyqin
Спасибо вам большое, а подскажите еще как лучше выводить переменные 
{{test['test']}}
или
test.test
?

Comment: @Andrey Kartavtsev, без разницы, но на мой взгляд, доступ как к свойству объекта выглядит красивее.

Comment: @andreyqin а еще вот вопрос у меня смотрите мы назначили
{% set hash = get.hash %}
А как теперь можно ее использовать? Если вот у меня идет выборка из базы данных с другого вообще файла? и мне нужна это переменная hash чтобы выборка работала.

Comment: @Andrey Kartavtsev, никак не использовать и пересмотреть структуру своего приложения, потому что инициализация переменных в шаблоне и использование их в моделе (там, где у вас происходит взаимодействие с базой) - крайне не верный подход. Либо, раз уж так необходимо - производите эту проверку на стороне сервера.